# Method of raw data via php wrappers? Throws an error

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache

I am experimenting with this wrapper, in particular pulling raw data from HTTP requests. Regarding cURL:

```
Protocol php not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Looked in my phpinfo and this is what is supported:

```
dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
```

Is there a way in PHP (if possible using this wrapper) to pull the raw data from arbitrary requests (without adding php to that list via configuration file)?

Answer (score 0):

probably better to use:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

as cURL does a new connection therefore may not be able to access the data which was sent together with the request.

Comment: ah yeah sorry - still as cURL has no access to the current request I would say that it cannot access the data.

Comment: Another thing is that cURL is less likely to work than file_get_contents etc. as it requires additional software in the system and php compiled with cURL support. Sometimes you can also use:  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, but this too would need to be enabled in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP DOC is clear there is a big difference between `http://` and `php://` your question is like asking why `chrome://` is not working in `firefox`

> PHP provides a number of miscellaneous I/O streams that allow access to PHP's own input and output streams, the standard input, output and error file descriptors, in-memory and disk-backed temporary file streams, and filters that can manipulate other file resources as they are read from and written to.

```
php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr
```

> php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process. The stream references a duplicate file descriptor, so if you open php://stdin and later close it, you close only your copy of the descriptor-the actual stream referenced by STDIN is unaffected. Note that PHP exhibited buggy behavior in this regard until PHP 5.2.1. It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.

Here a typical usage

```
$temp = fopen("php://temp", "r+");

$curl = curl_init("__YOUR__URL");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $temp);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

fseek($temp, 0);
while(! feof($temp)) {
    echo fgets($temp);
}
fclose($temp);
```